# Wordpress showing directory listing with Apache mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, vhosts

I have an issue where my Wordpress site is just showing the directory listing and not the application when I access crmpicco.localhost.

This is `/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`:

```
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/var/www/crmpicco/"
ServerName crmpicco.localhost:443
ServerAlias www.crmpicco.localhost
ServerAdmin crmpicco@crmpicco.com
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log"
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory "/var/www/crmpicco">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/crmpicco/wordpress">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Alias /app /var/www/crmpicco/symfony/web
Alias / /var/www/crmpicco/wordpress

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

I didn't have `mod_rewrite` enabled, which I thought was the issue, but I now have that enabled and it shows under `loaded_modules` in `phpinfo();`

> core mod_so http_core prefork mod_authn_file mod_authn_core
>   mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user mod_authz_core
>   mod_access_compat mod_auth_basic mod_socache_shmcb mod_reqtimeout
>   mod_filter mod_mime mod_log_config mod_env mod_headers mod_setenvif
>   mod_version mod_ssl mod_unixd mod_status mod_autoindex mod_vhost_alias
>   mod_dir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_php7

The `.htaccess` file that lives in the `/var/www/crmpicco/wordpress` directory looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I clearly have some mis-configuration somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of this by removing the `Alias` on `/` and having the `/wordpress` directory as the `DocumentRoot`.

The relevant lines are:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/crmpicco/wordpress"
ServerName crmpicco.localhost:443
ServerAlias www.crmpicco.localhost
ServerAdmin crmpicco@crmpicco.com
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log"

<Directory "/var/www/crmpicco/wordpress/">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride all
</Directory>

Alias /app /var/www/crmpicco/symfony/web

...

</VirtualHost>
```